# Unable to restore 1.72 version of Chevron.AzureAD.AspNet.Forms

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have added CvxArtifacroryPat to NuGet Packages. Even after adding the NuGet package I an still encountering this issue : 
[enter image description here](https://i)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc2VK.png).stack.imgur.com/rj7zC.png

Comment: It is not clear what your are asking. Please add more details about what is the issue and what have you tried in order to solve it

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to restore 1.72 version of Chevron.AzureAD.AspNet.Forms

Since your picture is not clear enough to the specific error messages about this issue, l assume that this issue is more related to the compatibility of your nuget package, package source url,nuget cache and so on.

**Suggestion**:

**First**, please check whether you can access the `CvxArtifacroryPat` URL. You can try to access this link on the website. And please note that you should access the URL which can reach the nuget package URL like this:

[image]

**Second**, when you restore package, you should check whether the `Allow Nuget to download missing packages` is selected.=>`Tools-->Options-->Nuget Package Manager-->Gneral-->Package Restore`. This is the equivalent of restoring the packet switch in VS.

**Third**, when you install this package, please note the nuget package's info like this:

[image]

These are some of the specific dependencies for this nuget to install into the project, so if your project does not meet these needs, it will turn out the error. Please

**Fourth**, when the nuget package is recovered, a damaged nuget package that was previously 
downloaded exists in the nuget cache(the recovery package will first look for the package from the local global cache) and the recovery fails. [Clean the nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) will solve the issue in this situation.

**Fifth**, please check whether the URLs which you selected are available. When you download the nuget from it, it will check the URLs and download the packages from them and if the URLs which you selected is not available or beingless, it will also turn out the error. So if the link are not useful, please delete them or uncheck them.

**In addition**, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495596/nuget-package-install-fails-package-restore-failed-rolling-back-package-change). Please run the `Update-Package -Reinstall` in the [Nuget Package Management Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio#package-manager-console) to eliminates errors caused by incompatibilities.

If you have any concern, please feel free to let us know.